# compare 2 dates by combining date and time

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var dateStart = $('input[id=orderdate-0]').val();
    var timeStart = $('input[id=ordertime-0]').val();
    var dateEnd = $('input[id=orderdate-1]').val();
    var timeEnd = $('input[id=orderime-1]').val();

    var startDate = new Date(dateStart + " " + timeStart);
    var endDate = new Date(dateEnd + " " + timeEnd);
     startDate.getTime();
    alert(startDate);
```

i am trying to combine dateStart which is '2013-12-11' and timeStart which is '11:00' and trying to generate date out of it. But i get alert like invalid date. Is there anything wrong in code.?

Comment: for date string argument for constructor supported format is new Date("October 13, 1975 11:13:00")

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` constructor is [very particular](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) about the date string formats it accepts.

Examples:

- Dec 25, 1995
- Wed, 09 Aug 1995 00:00:00
- 2011-10-10T14:48:00 (JavaScript 1.8.5+)

There is another constructor that take in the individual components of the date. If you break up your date strings into components you can use the following:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use moment JS plugin http://momentjs.com/

It's a date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.

Answer (score -1):

That is [not a valid format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for the `parse` function, you can use this instead:

```
var arr = dateStart.split('-');
var timeArr = timeStart.split(':');
new Date(arr[0], arr[1] -1, arr[2], timeArr[0] -1, timeArr[1] -1);
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qNbKr/)